# How to split image name from path in php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am trying to split the image name(with ext) from a path and save it and also save the path without image name in other field in DB. But i dont get any solution that how can i split it.

i use this code it gives me only the image name not the path here is my code

```
$url = $dataa['file_url'];          
$path = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' ) );
```

It gives me only image name not the path.

My images name are dynamically and also paths are dynamically like this

```
http://www.werb_url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/1.jpg
http://www.werb_url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/first.png
http://www.werb_url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/2.jpg
http://www.werb_url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/second.gif
```

I want image path "behalf of image name" and image name like this

```
$path = http://www.werb_url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/
$image = 1.jpg
```

How can i get the image path from image name. Any idea how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use php [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function

Answer (score 1):

Then use pathinfo

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo('http://www.werb_url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/1.jpg');
$pathname = $pathinfo['dirname'];
$filename = $pathinfo['basename'];
```

Comment: I want paths dynamically from image name

Comment: Sorry Bro @shah rukh give me this idea before you so i accept his answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$imagename=basename($Image_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this

```
$url="http://www.werb_url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/1.jpg";
$imagename=basename($url);
$myurl=str_replace($imagename,'',$url);
echo $myurl."<br />";
echo $imagename;
```

Comment: What is $bs can you explain me

Comment: sorry i had given $bs for image name when i tried and posted it without updating i.e replacing image name by empty will fetch you the URL

Comment: Your idea also great thanx alot

Answer (score 1):

```
html>
 <head>
   <title>Image name and path</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
   $url = 'http://www.werb_url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/1.jpg';
   $image_name = end(explode('/',$url));
   $image_path = str_replace($image_name, "", $url);
   print_r("Image Name : ".$image_name."</br>Image Path   : ".$image_path);
  ?>
</body>
```